# Match a string after the third colon and before 4th colon. If only 1 colon, match the entire string (Regex)

Tags: regex, expression

This is quite a complicated regex (Maybe for me) so hopefully my explanation will be clear.

Specifications:

- **First colon counting after a square bracket**

  `[1234]:` <- This is the first colon
- **Match a string after the 3rd colon and before the 4th colon**

  `[1234]: abc : 0 : xyz :` <- It will match `xyz` because it is after the 3rd colon and before the 4th colon
- **And if it do not have another colon after the 1st, it will match the whole string after the 1st colon after a square bracket**
  `[1234]: abc def ghi` <- It will match the whole string `abc def ghi` after 1st colon as it don't have another colon.

A few examples below:

> xxxx[2114]: debug : 0 : ABC::CheckIdleTimeout() : slot=2  0x00000000 RC_OK

Should match **ABC** only

> xxxx[13312]: info : 0 : user login : admin : xx.xxx.xx.xx/123

Should match **user login** only

> xxxx[12898]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user admin

Should match **session opened for user admin** only

> xxxx[12898]: Accepted password for admin from xx.xxx.xx.xx port 123

Should match the whole string after colon **Accepted password for admin from xx.xxx.xx.xx port 123**

======

What I have currently probably will not help but maybe it can be a starting point for you.

```
\[(.*?)\]:\s(\w.*)
```

It only match the string after `[xxxx]:`

I am using ruby regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is a bit complicated because it has to match to completely different cases at a time:

```
^.*?\[.*?\]:(?:[^:]*?:[^:]*?: *([^:]*?) *(?=$|:).*| *([^:]*?) *)$
```

The capturing groups are \1 and \2. You can use their concatenation because they are mutually exclusive. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/HWjsz8/1).

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/FNgZeJeJSJ) on rubular.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:[^:]+:){3}([^:]+?(?:$|:))|^(?:[^:]+:)([^:]+$)
```

It returns the desired substrings in the first and second capture groups. How to access these groups depends on the language you're using.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6jWZlX/2

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Amazing!